# YouTube Data API - embedding paid for videos

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to embed a player (perhaps YouTube) into a website which plays movies rented or purchased via Google Play?

My end goal is to have a user purchase a movie via Google Play, then have that movie available to watch within the site.

I've purchased a movie for testing purposes - `https://www.youtube.com/embed/kX1uUmXNNII`.
When I load that link while logged in to Google, the movie plays. Open a private tab, same link, and I get the trailer - which makes sense.

So far I've got OAuth set up with a YouTube Data API along with an iFrame

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600px" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kX1uUmXNNII" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

When I login and redirect back, the same link errors with `Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available.`

Which seems to not be correct, given I'm running a recent version of Chrome. Previous attempts with another set of Google API credentials caused it to play the trailer to the movie.